# Are git branches isolated from master?

Tags: git

Assume this scenario:

1 - I checkout master, and do a `git pull` to get the latest

2 - I checkout my own new branch from master `git checkout -b my-branch`

3 - Few days pass, I stash my branch changes, checkout master and  do `git pull` again

4 - I checkout back to my own branch `git checkout my-branch`

Now the new changes in master (from step 3) are also present in my branch, how is that possible?
I thought a branch is an isolated branch from master.

Comment: What do you mean stashing your changes on the branch? Did you commit your changes on the branch? If you didn't commit they will be present when you change branches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing something wrong. The new changes from master can't appear on your local branch. It breaks the whole git idea.

Just to be sure tested it on new folder with file. I commited it as "1st" commit, then perfomed checkout to new branch `my-branch`, then stashed some file edits on it and checkouted back to `master`. Then I created "2nd" commit and checkouted to `my-branch` and, of course, everything is the same as in "1st" commit because I branched from it and create `my-branch` ref on "1st" commit.